# Spreadsheet generation for both Microsoft Excel and Open/Libre office

Tags: java, excel, xlsx, openoffice-calc, ods

I need to generate programmatically with Java 2 spreadsheets with the same content, that differ in the file format.
One for .xlsx and one for .ods

As far as I understand I have 2 options:

1. Use 2 spreadsheet generation libraries (I would opt out for Apache POI and Apache ODFDOM)
2. Use 1 library. Generate either .xlsx or .ods and then use a converter library.

The question is - which one is better?. However that is too vague of a question.

- What is the quality of conversion from .xlsx to .ods (and vice versa) and what Java libraries would you recommend?
- How does the performance compare between the two? Performance is not important, but if one method is twice as fast/takes up half the memory, I would opt out for that method. (Actually memory footprint is fairly important).
- Any other comments from experience?

PS. The size of the documents can vary dramatically - from 1 row to a thousand.
The generation is happening on a server.

EDIT: There are no formulas present yet, but it is something that I have not given any thought yet. The main point of the switch from CSV is for formatting, and there is probably not much that can be done with formulas.

Comment: Do you just need values, or do you have to output formulas into the sheets as well?

Comment: No formulas, at least not as of yet

Comment: Ah, that edit nixed my suggestion of using CSVs, I don't know of anything, good luck!